# array_filter($_POST) - exclude some form fields

Tags: php

I'm using `array_filter($_POST);` to insert in to a DB

```
$db->insert('customers', $data_to_db);
```

However, I have a few fields I want to exclude from the input - as they're not database fields.

Is there a way I can easily exclude in the array_filter?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the unwanted fields after you filter.

```
unset($data_to_db['field1']);
unset($data_to_db['field2']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the ones you want and compute the intersection:

```
$result = array_intersect_key($_POST, ['keep1'=>true, 'keep2'=>true]);
```

Or in the filter:

```
$fields = ['keep1', 'keep2'];
$result = array_filter($_POST, function($v, $k) use($fields) {
                                   return in_array($k, $fields);
                               }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

If you are using the filter to remove empty values then:

```
$result = array_filter($_POST, function($v, $k) use($fields) {
                                   return !empty($v) && in_array($k, $fields);
                               }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

However, if you use a multidimensional array in the form it is much easier:

```
<input name="data[keep1]" . . . >
<input name="data[keep2]" . . . >
```

Then you just use `$_POST['data']` when inserting.